# Scrollbar cannot show the entire list as the list passes below webpage

Tags: html, css, angular

I have been working on this problem where I have 100 selected users and I cannot see them even if I have a scroll bar.This is a grid for users which is dynamic depends on user, So when I'm selecting more users in the list, It will go below my screen and most below records are not visible even if scroll is there  but the scroll is not scrollable to the end of the grid.  (Refer the attached GIF).[Reffer this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0vPu.gif)

```
<ul id="filter-users" role="tablist" class="filter-list" *ngIf="getFilterUsers.length > 0" [@fadeAnimation]>
  <li class="panel" id="qa-user{{filter.NameFilter}}" *ngFor="let filter of getFilterUsers; let ind = index"
    [@fadeAnimation]>
    <div class="filter-list__cont-menu-item-name" [ngClass]="{'active': filter.NameFilter === selectedTitleUser}"
      data-parent="#filter-users" data-toggle="collapse" role="tab" [attr.data-target]="'#filter-users' + ind"
      aria-expanded="false" (click)="onTitleUser(filter.NameFilter)">
      <div class="cont-icon">
        <span class="closeicon">&#x0229E;</span>
        <span class="openicon">&#x0229F;</span>
      </div>
      <span class="main-name" [ngClass]="{'color-txt': this.chageColorUser.length ? findNameSod(filter.NameFilter) : false}">{{filter.NameFilter}}</span>
      <div id="qa-userremoveuser" class="remove-user-btn" (click)="onRemoveUser(filter.Id);"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse filter-list__cont-sub-menu" role="tabpanel" id="filter-users{{ind}}" aria-expanded="false">
      <ul>
        <li class="subfilter-name"  
          data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
          *ngFor="let subFilter of filter.SubFilters" 
          title="{{subFilter.Name}}" 
          id="qa-user{{subFilter.Name}}" 
          [@fadeAnimation]>
          {{subFilter.Name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS here

```
.filter-list {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0 !important;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: $white;
    // padding: 15px 0;
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;

    li {
        position: relative;
    }

    .panel {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: none;

        &.hideFilter {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    &__cont-menu-item-name {
        background-color: white;
        // padding: 3px;
        color : #333333;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        padding: 7px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;

        .glyphicon {
            color: $gray6;
            transform: rotate(0);
            transition: transform 0.3s;
        }

        .cont-icon {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 11px;
            top: -1.5px;
            margin-left: 13px;
            margin-right: 5px;

            .openicon {
                display: none;
            }

            .closeicon {
                display: block;
            }
        }

        .main-name {
            // color: $white;
            // font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
        .color-txt {
            color: $red1;
        }

        .remove-user-btn {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: -2px;
            font-size: 16px;
            // color: $white;
        }

        &:hover {
            background-color: $blue1;
            color: $white;

            .glyphicon {
                color: $white;
            }
        }

        &.active {
            background-color: $blue1 !important;
            color: $white !important;

            .cont-icon {
                .openicon {
                    display: block !important;
                }

                .closeicon {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &__cont-sub-menu {
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            background-color: white;
            color: #333333;
            max-height: auto;
            overflow-y: auto;

            li {
                // padding: 0 10px 0 35px;
                cursor: default;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
                padding-top: 6px;
                padding-bottom: 6px;
                padding-left: 28px;
                padding-right: 12px;
                /* &:hover {
                    background-color: $blue2;
                } */

                &:first-child {
                     padding-top: 6px;
                }

                &:last-child {
                    padding-bottom: 6px;
                }
            }

            li .panel {
                box-shadow: none;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO! please create a fiddle or sth similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on css class filter-list `height: 100%;` Try something like `calc ( 100% -100px )` The `100px` need to change till you see all. Most time there are some maring and padding which should be subtracted from your 100%